# How to incorporate Win32 in an SDL project?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, visual-studio-2012, sdl-2

I made some software using SDL and OpenGL, and now I would like to add a graphical interface for input, like some textboxes and buttons. I realize that this probably would have to be in a separate window, which I don't mind, but I have no clue how to incorporate Win32 functionality in my project. I tried changing the definition of my main function from

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    ...
}
```

But I get an errors that say:

```
LNK2005: _WinMain@16 already defined in SDL2main.lib (SDL_windows_main.obj)
LNK2005: _WinMain@16 already defined in Source.obj
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
Is there a way to solve this, or is there an alternative way to create forms in c++?

Thanks

Comment: The GUI doesn't have to be in a separate window. You just need widgets that can render to opengl. There are gui libraries that do that.

Answer (score 2):

SDL defines `main` as a macro. It's like the ultimate horror show. Mixing Microsoft's `WinMain` monstrosity into that might seem appropriate, of course, but it isn't needed for anything.

Instead just keep your `main`.

If I had committed to using SDL (which, considering the above, I would never do), then I would first of all check out what SDL offers in the way of textboxes and buttons and such. If none, then just include `<windows.h>` properly (defining `STRICT` and `NOMINMAX` and `UNICODE` first), and use the API. But for that I suggest learning that API first by creating some pure API programs, with no interfering SDL.

Comment: To extend this - because it seems like `WinMain` is already defined by the library, you can just continue using `main`. If you don't want the console, just change your executable output type (under project linker settings).

Comment: What do you mean by 'use main'? If I used my existing main function, how can I have Win32 functionality, where would I get my hInstance and stuff from?

Comment: @HarWiltz: An instance handle is mostly only needed for resources. The call `GetModuleHandle(0)` retrieves an instance handle for the current executable, if you have resources there. Pass it a DLL name to get an instance handle to some loaded DLL. Ask new SO questions for new problems. SO comments are designed to not support discussion, so you can imagine that a tutorial is somewhat beyond the design limits.

Comment: They could at least give you a choice, like a SDLmain macro, before messing with your program. This is probably done for portability reasons.